# Adding in forms into django detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a model fie, a forms.py file and a views.py file. The views file returns a detail view of a post, now I wish to add a model form of a comments model into the detail view so I can access it in d template as {{ form }}. I can do this with function-based views but finding it difficult to do with class-based views. Here are the code.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to='post_images')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)



class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_commented = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


#forms.py
from django import forms
from users.models import Profile
from Post.models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text', ]



#views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'Post/blog-detail.html'
```

Hope my question makes sense Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, for example:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'Post/blog-detail.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
        return context
```

Comment: HEllo Vlad. Withnthis how do I access the form in the template? {{form}} or {{comment_form}}?

Comment: @Cole in template you can get CommentForm by {{comment_form}}

Comment: hey Vlad, I got an error:

descriptor '__init__' of 'super' object needs an argument

Comment: Updated, try it now.